# Angular not loading bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am fairly new to Angular, and trying to implement bootstrap to a project. But I am not able load bootstrap to my project

when i am looking in inspect tool --> Sources --> CSS

`/* src/styles.css */ /* angular:styles/global:styles */ /*# sourceMappingURL=styles.css.map */`

I have added the bootstrap package through NPM, and are able to find it in my node_modules, I have linked it in my angular.json

`"styles": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css" ],`

What am i doing wrong?
I have followed this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bq9mvcuAmcQ

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you've followed the correct steps. Double-check if the path in `angular.json` under `styles` matches the actual location of Bootstrap's CSS file in `node_modules`. Also, ensure you've saved changes and restarted your Angular development server (`ng serve`) after adding the Bootstrap path. If it still doesn't work, try deleting the `node_modules` folder and `package-lock.json` file, then run `npm install` to reinstall your packages. This might resolve any path or dependency issues.